# How can I get a blurred Hillshade effect in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hillshade

Does anyone know how to achieve this blurred hillshade effect in QGIS? This one was produced by a former colleague and I can't find a way to replicate it. More specifically, what I can't achieve is that blurry effect.

[image: this]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 12):

You can find **Hillshade** in menu `Raster --> Analysis --> DEM (Terrain models)...` or in processing toolbox `Hillshade`.

Blurry effect can be achieved by changing resample method in `Style` tab in `Layer properties`

[image]